# Post data string to url via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a script that collects data from form submissions. If the data validates correctly, it creates a data string and posts it to another URL (which is a wordpress page) that collects the data and inserts the data into the posts table.

The Wordpress URL is working fine as its creating all the posts when I load it manually, but when I post the data via ajax, my console shows that the URL returns a 404 but when I curl the URL, it returns a 200.

The website is currently sitting on an internal staging URL so I can't provide any actual URLs.

Any assistance would be great.

Console error:

```
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

ajax Code:

```
submissionURL = "http://staging.ccc.site.edu.au/process/"
jQuery.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : submissionURL, 
        data : dataString,  
        success : function() {
            jQuery('form#enquiry_form_main').hide();
            jQuery('.enquiryMessage').html("<div id='SubmitMessage'></div>");
            jQuery('#SubmitMessage').html('<h3>Thank you for your enquiry</h3><p>One of our Staff managers will respond to your enquiry as soon as possible. </p><p>A copy of your request will be sent to your email address, along with any reply email. If you do not receive these please ensure you check your junk box. </p>').hide().fadeIn(1500, function() {
                jQuery('#message');
            });
        }
    });
```

console curl results

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Date: Thu, 29 May 2014 01:48:29 GMT
 Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
 X-Pingback: http://staging.ccc.site.edu.au/xmlrpc.php
 Link: <http://staging.ccc.site.edu.au/?p=680>; rel=shortlink
 Vary: Accept-Encoding
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: What command are you using to post with the curl?

Comment: curl -I http://staging.ccc.site.edu.au/process/